# How to store TcpStream inside a HashMap?

Tags: rust

I'm new to Rust and I'm trying to create a Server struct which listen to an address and starts a TCP socket connection. The problem is that I want to store the client connection inside a hash map so I can use it later..

I tried writing this:

```
use std::collections::HashMap;
use std::net::TcpListener;
use std::net::TcpStream;
use std::sync::{Arc, RwLock};
use std::thread;

#[derive(Clone, Debug)]
pub struct Server {
    id: Arc<RwLock<u32>>,
    connections: Arc<RwLock<HashMap<u32, TcpStream>>>,
    url: String,
}

impl Server {
    pub fn new(url: String) -> Server {
        let server = Server {
            id: Arc::new(RwLock::new(0)),
            connections: Arc::new(RwLock::new(HashMap::new())),
            url,
        };

        server
    }

    pub fn start(&self) {
        thread::spawn(move || {
            let mut listener =
                TcpListener::bind(self.clone().url).expect("Could not start the server");

            println!("Server started succesfully");

            for stream in listener.incoming() {
                match stream {
                    Ok(stream) => self.on_client_connect(stream),
                    Err(error) => eprintln!("Error when tried to use stream"),
                }
            }
        });
    }

    fn on_client_connect(&mut self, stream: TcpStream) {
        let id = self.id.read().unwrap();
        self.connections.read().unwrap().insert(id, stream);
        let id = self.id.write().unwrap();
        *id += 1;
    }
}
```

But of course this doesn't work.. There are 2 things that I don't understand, the first is how to pass the stream into my function and then store in my connections hash map so I can use it later and how to use my id inside my on_client_connect function.

Comment: Apparently you cannot pass a stream itself, you can pass a reference (with `&`).

Comment: I tried that, but then the compiler complains about the lifetime and I couldn't get to work :( if you provide me a way with reference that works, I'll accept your answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's quite a few issues that need minor fixes in this code.

The first one I ran into was the usage of self in the `thread::spawn` closure.
The thread::spawn needs its argument to have static lifetime, but we've no guarantee that the Server object lives that long.

I solved it by cloning the Server object and moving that into the closure. This is OK as all its data is already behind `Arc`s.

The next problem was `self.connections.read().unwrap().insert(*id, stream);` needs to get a `write` lock, not a `read`.

Finally `id+=1` needs to dereference `id`.

Once these were fixed, it seems that storing the TcpStream is not an issue. (At least using nightly). I'd thought I'd need to box the TcpStream - but it seems OK as is.

You can see that it compiles [in the playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=release&edition=2018&gist=899eb429ffe0534be633259e2b1f98cd)

```
use std::collections::HashMap;
use std::net::TcpListener;
use std::net::TcpStream;
use std::sync::{Arc, RwLock};
use std::thread;

#[derive(Clone, Debug)]
pub struct Server {
    id: Arc<RwLock<u32>>,
    connections: Arc<RwLock<HashMap<u32, TcpStream>>>,
    url: String,
}

impl Server {
    pub fn new(url: String) -> Server {
        let server = Server {
            id: Arc::new(RwLock::new(0)),
            connections: Arc::new(RwLock::new(HashMap::new())),
            url,
        };

        server
    }

    pub fn start(&self) {
        let mut self_clone = self.clone();
        thread::spawn(move || {
            let mut listener =
                TcpListener::bind(&self_clone.url).expect("Could not start the server");

            println!("Server started succesfully");

            for stream in listener.incoming() {
                match stream {
                    Ok(stream) => self_clone.on_client_connect(stream),
                    Err(error) => eprintln!("Error when tried to use stream"),
                }
            }
        });
    }

    fn on_client_connect(&mut self, stream: TcpStream) {
        let id = self.id.read().unwrap();
        self.connections.write().unwrap().insert(*id, stream);
        let mut id = self.id.write().unwrap();
        *id += 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: It worked, thanks! Just one more question, how do I read from the buffer inside my on_client_connect function? I'm trying but I can't make it work..

Answer (score 2):

You need to clone outside of `thread::spawn` and move the cloned instance in thread scope.

Also, `on_client_connect` do not need `&mut self` because the fields `id` and `connections` are already protected inside `RwLock`.

```rust
use std::net::TcpListener;
use std::net::TcpStream;
use std::collections::HashMap;
use std::sync::{Arc, RwLock};
use std::thread;

#[derive(Clone, Debug)]
pub struct Server {
    id: Arc<RwLock<u32>>,
    connections: Arc<RwLock<HashMap<u32, TcpStream>>>,
    url: String,
}

impl Server {
    pub fn new(url: String) -> Server {
        let server = Server {
            id: Arc::new(RwLock::new(0)),
            connections: Arc::new(RwLock::new(HashMap::new())),
            url,
        };

        server
    }

    pub fn start(&self) {
        let me = self.clone(); // Clone it outside
        thread::spawn(move || {
            let mut listener = TcpListener::bind(&me.url).expect("Could not start the server");

            println!("Server started succesfully");

            for stream in listener.incoming() {
                match stream {
                    Ok(stream) => me.on_client_connect(stream),
                    Err(error) => eprintln!("Error when tried to use stream"),
                }
            }
        });
    }

    fn on_client_connect(&self, stream: TcpStream) { // `&mut self` not needed as the id, connection are inside the lock
        let mut id = self.id.write().unwrap();
        self.connections.write().unwrap().insert(*id, stream);
        *id += 1;
    }
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=b81ece60ce92bd607af86de1b33aa7c4)